Probability of the Maximum of $6$ die rolls
Someone please explain to me why this is wrong. Here is the question:

If I roll $6$ different fair $6$-sided dice, what is the probability that the maximum of the rolls is $5$?

My approach was to find the the PDF of the Maximum, then evaluate at $x = 5$:

Let $f (\text{Max})$ be the PDF of the maximum, then $f (\text{Max}) = \frac{6!}{5!} \frac{1}{6} F (\text{Max})^5$, which is $\left( \frac{\text{Max}}{6} \right)^5$.

Evaluating at $\text{Max} = 5$, gives us $\left( \frac{5}{6} \right)^5$.

I know this is actually the CDF of the maximum here, but where did I go wrong in my derivation of the PDF?



Why are you raising things to the fifth power?  You have $6$  rolls, right?  In any case, the probability that the max is at most $n$ is $\left( \frac n6\right)^6$.  You can compute the answer using that.

You have 6 rolls, but one is fixed at the  maximum to ensure that the maximum is present in the 6 rolls.  I know that the probability of getting a maximum of 5 using the CDF is (5/6)^5 - (5/6)^4.  But, why is my derived PDF incorrect?

You don't provide a derivation.  At least, not one that I can follow.  You know the actual PDF, so you know the one you wrote isn't right.

To your point:  you can't just fix one of the rolls to be $5$...that overcounts the cases in which more than one roll is a $5$.

How would you apply the general formula for the distribution of an order statistic given in most textbooks in this case?

Should have said:  your CDF based formula is also wrong.  The probability that the max is equal to $n$ is $P(\max ≤n)-P(\max ≤ (n-1))=\left(\frac n6\right)^6 -\left(\frac {n-1}6\right)^6$.

Ok, but how then would you derive the PDF for the maximum in this case?  Why isn't the PDF (x/6)^5?

I have said repeatedly how to do that, in my prior comment I wrote out the exact formula.  Note that your guess is wrong even in the case $x=5$.  The answer in that case is clearly $\left(\frac 16\right)^6$ since the only way to have a max of $1$ is for all rolls to be $1$.

Ok, but most intro stats textbooks offer the following formula for finding the PDF of an order statistic:
gi(y) = [n!/(i-1)!(n-1)!][F(y)]^i-1[1-F(y)]^n-i*f(y)
How would you apply the above formula to find the equation for the pdf in this example.  As, I stated I tried to do this in my framing of the question but got the wrong answer.  Can you "explain" why I got the wrong PDF?  If not, could you use the above formula to derive the correct PDF?

I have already said what's wrong with yours, and I can't read the expression you wrote.  What are $gi, y, n, i, F, f$?  In any case, I have shown you how to derive the correct formula.  I suggest studying that.  Good luck.

F is the function for the CDF, n is the number of random variables "samples," in this case 6 because there are 6 rolls. gi is the pdf for the ith order statistic. i is the ith order statistic - in this case 5. f(y) is the PDF of x, the random variable - in this case that would be 1/6 since the die has 6 faces.
Also, the question is asking how to find the PDF using the above generalized formula for an order statistic.  That's what I'm confused about.
The formula is given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic under the Cumulative distribution function of order statistics

Sorry, I'm not going to try to parse all of that.  The distribution you asked about in your post is very easily understood directly.  If you intended to ask an entirely different question, I suggest that you post it separately.

ok.... thanks.... I guess.

The CDF of the maximum roll is easy to find. Consider $x \in \{ 1, \dots, 6 \}$. If $x$ is the maximum of all the rolls, then each roll must be at most $x$. The probability of this is $F (x) = P [\max \le x] = \left( \frac{x}{6} \right)^N$, where $N$ is the number of dice.
Since $\max$ is a discrete random variable, then a probability mass function is more applicable, and you have $f (x) = F (x) - F (x - 1)$ in this case. Evaluating for $N = 6$ dice and $x = 5$, you obtain simply
$$P [\max = 5] = f (5) = F (5) - F (4) = \boxed{\left( \frac{5}{6} \right)^6 - \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^6}$$
In particular, because the random variable is not continuous, differentiating the CDF to obtain the probability mass (as it looks like you have done) is incorrect.

I did not differentiate the CDF. I used this formula in the cumulative distribution section here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic to find the PDF of the maximum, where n = 6, k = 6.

@HaikVoskerchian Please double-check the preceding paragraph on that page: "From now on, we will assume that the random variables under consideration are continuous..." (emphasis mine). Your random variables are decidedly not continuous.

Thank you; I see now.
